# Dealing with Nulls in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ statement that looks like this:

```
List<Product> products = Product.GetAll();
List<Department> departments = Deparment.GetAll();

var productList = (from product in products
               select new
               {
                 ProductId= product.ID,
                 ProductName = product.Name,
                 Departments = departments.Where(d => product.DepartmentIDs.Contains(d.Id)).ToList() 
               });
```

My problem is, the `product.DepartmentIDs` field might be null. This is due to a recent database change. This change is causing my code to break. How do I update my `Where` clause that retrieves the departments to only get the departments if `product.DepartmentIDs` is not null? `product.DepartmentIDs` will either be `null` or a `List<int>`.

Comment: You should be doing this work on the database end, not in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
departments.Where(d => 
      product.DepartmentIDs != null && product.DepartmentIDs.Contains(d.Id)).ToList()
```